# Android Studio AVD Trouble

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am using Android Studios 0.8.1 on Windows 8. I cannot seem to create a new AVD.

Here is a screenshot of the problem: 
[image]

As you can see, at the bottom of the window, the "OK" button is disabled.

Does anyone see a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try typing in 64 in the SD card size box. that gives you a 64 MB sdcard in the emulator.

Comment: Also choose a skin! And I'm quite sure Android L is only supported on nexus 5 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html)

Try to follow these steps:
To set up an Android Wear virtual device:

```
1- Click Tools > Android > AVD Manager.
2- Click Create....
3- Fill in the following details for the AVD you want to specify and leave the rest of the fields with their default values:
    AVD Name - A name for your AVD
    Device - Android Wear Round or Square device types
    Target - Android 4.4W - API Level 20
    CPU/ABI - Android Wear ARM (armeabi-v7a)
    Keyboard - Select Hardware keyboard present
    Skin - AndroidWearRound or AndroidWearSquare depending on the selected device type
    Snapshot - Not selected
    Use Host GPU - Selected, to support custom activities for wearable notifications
4- Click OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either snapshot or "Use Host GPU", not both. Try deselecting one.